# How to open .msg file in Outlook

Tags: java, outlook

I have got question which already was in StackOverflow but maybe something changed. 
After creating emails using JavaMail API i would like to open it in .msg format. So i save this message on my disk, but im not able to open it. When im trying to open them i see warning message "You can't open this file. It is possible that this message does not exist, you dont have permission to open it or its already open in different program." Im using writeTo to save file on disk:

```
message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\mail.msg")));
```

When i saving emial in .eml format it's working fine but it not satisfied me because its not ready to send... I dont want to use mailto, because i want use HTML body.
I wrote something about Apache POI, but im not able to  tell if it is solution.

I would be grateful for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply change EML file's extension to MSG, this does not make it an MSG file.

EML file should work just fine. To make sure it opens in the unsent state, set the `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check .msg extension is exist in IIS server

if not exists
 create the  new .msg  extension
  Mime Type: application/vnd.ms-outlook

[image: Add MIME Type]